# Deleting rows from DataFrame if specific conditions are met

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains aircraft flight data. I want to filter this data based on aircraft's position (ie. Climb, cruise, descent etc). This data has 27 columns and more than 350k rows.

If Altitude is higher than 28980 ft, climb rate is between -2.5/2.5 and flight path angle is between -3.2e-3/3.2e-3, I want to select that row.

I am trying use the code below.

```
climb = climb[(climb['Altitude (ft)'] > 28980) & (-2.5<climb['Altitude Dot (ft/s)'] <2.5) & (-3.2e-3<climb['Gamma (rad)']<3.2e-3)]
```

But I am getting this error.

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split your second condition in two conditions.

```
(-2.5<climb['Altitude Dot (ft/s)'] <2.5)
```

Change it for:

```
(-2.5 < climb['Altitude Dot (ft/s)']) & ( climb['Altitude Dot (ft/s)'] < 2.5)
```